# Redirect user to the login form of another web app and wait for a response(a token) from the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, httpresponse, http-redirect

We have a company building a web application for us and they want to authenticate using our existing website. I have written a login form that authenticates the user and needs to send back a token they can use for all future calls. At the moment I'm setting a cookie before redirecting back to their web app but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Also, I need to test what I have built but not sure how to redirect to a login page and wait for that token response.

Answer (score 1):

Token based authentication is stateless. You are not storing any information about your user on the server or in a session.
This concept alone takes care of many of the problems with having to store information on the server.

Although this implementation can vary, the gist of it is as follows:

1. User Requests Access with Username / Password
2. Application validates credentials
3. Application provides a signed token to the client
4. Client stores that token and sends it along with every request
5. Server verifies token and responds with data

More info here [The Ins and Outs of Token Based Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication)

Here's an infographic to explain the process:

[image: infographic to explain the process]

Comment: Thank you for you answer.. This is what I'm trying to achieve but once the user hits the login button I authenticate the user and create a token. I now need to send it back to the client. for the moment I set a cookie with the token and send back a response. I'm not sure if that is the normal way to do it. I'm currently doing it like this

<==HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("title","value")==>